# Multiple Packing Slip Reports in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reporting

here's my issue.  I am using SSRS 2005 to create a series of packing slips based on PO numbers that fit a certain criteria ('picked', to make it simple).

Each packing slip needs to have a page header and footer that contains information specific to that slip - page number, refund policy, order number, etc.  The body contains rows equal to each product in the slip.

I have all of the SQL down - that's not an issue.  I'm having trouble setting up the report (in VS) so that it pulls one version of the report for each PO.

I've tried using the packing list as a subreport, but that doesn't display the headers and footers.  I've tried grouping inside the table, but I am unable to make the table footer always display on the bottom of the page.

Any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ReportItems syntax in the Footer textboxes to refer to hidden textboxes in the body.